# CakePHP 3.6.11: Access property of joined tables in view

Tags: php, join, cakephp, model-view-controller, associations

I have this tables:

> customers[id, name, surname, phone, text, balance, created]
>
> service_types[id, title, price, length, is_subscription, created]
>
> customer_service_types[id, customer_id, service_type_id, price, created]

In `view.ctp` I want to see all the `Services` that are assigned to current Customer.

`Bake` Created this `view function` in `CustomersController.php`

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['CustomerServiceTypes']
        ]);

        $this->set('customer', $customer);
    }
```

And in `view.ctp` I want to display the `service_type -> title` so here is how I tried to do so:

`<td><?=$customerServiceTypes->service!==null ?  h($customerServiceTypes->service->title) : '' ?></td>`

But its always displays blank. How I can change it in order to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change view function as follows:

```
$customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['CustomerServiceTypes' => ['ServiceTypes']]
        ]);


        $this->set('customer', $customer);
```

In view.ctp:

```
<td><?= h($customerServiceTypes->service_type->title) ?></td>
```